# Bypass or fulfill unique constraint for large update

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, unique-constraint

I have a database of order line items. Two of the columns are for controlling batch processing. They're called `prod_batch_id` (number) and `prod_batch_index` (varchar2 - 10 byte). They both need to be either null or filled, and `prod_batch_index` has a unique index on it. To fetch unbatched orders we simply pull all records where `prod_batch_id` is null.

The table (`ord_lin`) has 171,602 records that pertain to a particular product line that I'm about to start batching. Rather than limit my batching queries by the date that we start I'd like to add all of those records to a dummy batch.

I'm not well versed in Oracle, or even SQL, so I don't know if it's possible but would there be a way to temporarily disable the unique constraint for the update, and then enable it again without it complaining about those records?

If that's not an option, how would I go about creating the unique values for each record during the update?

**Notes:** The batch system was originally made for a whole new product line and was designed this way because those products didn't exist before batching did. I will likely have several other product lines that will get switched to the batching system down the line, so I'll be back to this point again sooner or later.

I'm also aware that I could do things like make another field to act as a "batched" flag that doesn't have such constraints, but that would involve updating a lot of programs.

Comment: Can you lock the system for OLTP while the batch process is running? If so, you could disable the unique constraint while the batch is running, then ENABLE NOVALIDATE it afterwards. This would, mind you, cause the unique index to be dropped, and then recreated (as a non-unique index) afterwards. see: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF01111

Comment: This kind of update isn't part of the batching process. It's actually a way to prevent orders that have been processed the old way from showing up in the batching system. Once the initial update is done we'll want the unique constraint to still be followed.

Comment: my point is that the proposed solution I'm suggesting requires you to *make* it a batch process - i.e. it won't allow other processes to muck around with the data while it's running.

Comment: My problem has nothing to do with other processes affecting my data while I'm working with it. The batch fields are there to effectively remove the records from future batches.

Comment: You have misunderstood me. IF you disable the constraint, it WILL affect other processes that work with the data!